# is there any way to convert mongodb database to waterline db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, mongoose, waterline

I have a one file which has details of the database named xyz.js and another file which created the database using that file in mongodb and also has various functions like adding to database etc.The name of this file is create.js. Now I want to convert create.js code using mongodb to waterline.

Answer (score 2):

me_aj, there is no possible short and simple answer for what you want. Nor there is any tool that will do what you need. Here are some pointers for what you'll need to do.

### 1. Learn about using waterline

It may sound obvious but you should start by getting acquainted with waterline and the best places are the [waterline project](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) and the [Waterline Docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs).

By then you'll know waterline is an adapter based ORM and that you'll have to decide which adapter to use. If you are using mongodb, you are probably looking at [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo).

### 2. Config waterline to connect to the desired data store

Waterline, contrary to some other ORMs, has to be initialised before you can start using it. If you are using it outside sails you should look at [these examples](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/tree/master/example) on how to set up a simple app. You'll also need to configure it by following the specific adapter settings. If you are connecting to mongodb check the instructions on the sails-mongo project.

### 3. CRUD operations

By now you've setup waterline to initialise and connect to your chosen data store, now it's time to do things with it. Similar to many other ORMs. waterline uses methods such as `find`, `update`, `create` and `destroy` to perform CRUD operations, to learn more about using these check the [query methods](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-methods.md) documentation page.

This should be enough to point you in the right direction.